# Serial Communication between two microprocessor (H8S2633R) in C language

Tags: c, serial-communication, microprocessors

I am doing a school project that required communication between two microprocessor, I did not convert to RS232 for this communication as the two processor is place next to each other. The program should be able to send and receive the information.When the other party receive it, it will send back a letter back to the processor telling the processor that it has receive it. The program should be an interrupt driven and I am using the high-performance Embedded workshop to write the program. Please help me, struck at this for quite a while. Thanks :)

Comment: You have a higher chances to get the answer @ http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: init the serial port, the function of sending and receiving data

Answer (score 1):

[Download the data sheet](http://www.digchip.com/datasheets/download_datasheet.php?id=3215687&part-number=H8S2633R) for that processor (can one really call a 1500-page document a "data sheet"?) and read chapter 16, "Serial Communication Interface". In particular, it looks like you'll be most interested in section 16.3.3, "Multiprocessor Communication Function."